# Indentify numbers on screen

Tags: java, numbers, screen

What do you recomend to recognize a number on screen, and stores it, in real time.
  I'm working with Java, I'm new on this. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by: recognize a number on screen

Comment: Hi! I want to take numbers that show on screen another program running at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If by 'recognize a number on a screen' you mean to recognize a number that a user typed, I'd use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. It looks like this:

```
int userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
int number = userInput;
```

This stores the number that the user entered in the variable `number`.

I hope I answered your question

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I want to take the numbers that a program show on screen, and store them